# Using the static keyword to initialize a class, a variable vs a function in C++

Tags: c++

Assume the following code:

I understand that `static` in both C and C++ has 2 functions. Either to allocate variables in the `Data/BSS` section of memory (sort of global), or make the variable visible within the same translation unit or class during linking.

Are my code comments correct?

```
#include <iostream>

class test{
 public: 
 static int y;            // initialized in data section of memory. Has a scope till the lifetime of program, Only 1 instance during program lifetime between all class instances.
 static int get(int a){   // `get` can only access other static data. You can also use this without a class instance using test::get(). No effect on memory allocation or linkage.
   return y+a;
 }
};

int test::y = 6;          // initialized to 6 during compile time in `.data` section.

int main(){
 static test t;           // Using static here make the obj have a scope till the lifetime of program. No effect on memory allocation or linkage.
 std::cout << t.get(1) << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usage of memory section is implementation detail. (So can depend of compilers, ...).

Comment: If a class has linkage, its members cannot have internal linkage.

Comment: Linkage doesn't apply to local variable definitions (but a local declaration can introduce a global variable with `extern`)

Comment: Your `test::y` does not have dynamic initialization.  It's perfectly legal for the toolchain to prepopulate it with `6` such that it never has the value `0`.

Comment: @BenVoigt could you let me know if it looks better now? `static test t;` seems to be pointless? also `static int get(int a)` doesn't do much either?

Comment: `static test t;` specifically in `main()` doesn't behave much differently from omitting `static`.  With `static` it does result in the memory being prereserved instead of allocated from the thread stack, but in either case the object will live for the life of the program.  However, using `static` in a function *other* than main that can be called multiple times, and especially if it uses recursion, will change everything.

Comment: `static` in the class member function `static int get(int a)` prevents the function from having an implied parameter `test* const this` like a non-static member function would.  This means that the function can be called as `test::get(42)` without ever having an instance of the class.

Comment: In neither of those two cases is `static` changing the linkage.

Comment: Note that asking "Are my code comments correct?" and then changing the comments is changing the entire question.  Edits should be used to clarify, not to replace the question with a different question.

Comment: You tagged your question with `c++` without any relation to a specific compiler, runtime, os, binary format, … so strictly speaking this can only answered with respect to the abstract state machine specified by the c++ standard: so it would only be the interaction of the translation units and storage durations/lifetime. As soon as you go beyond this and talk about actual compilers, as-if rules have to be considered so your assumption might be true but done need to be, as the compiler could do anything as long as the as-if rule is not violated.

Answer (score -1):

Almost, but not quite.

Both `x` and `y` are initialised "at compile time". It does not matter whether you write the initialiser inline, or separately on a definition, except that usually you *have* to write a definition and you're currently missing one for `x`. (You get away with it in this toy example because you don't *odr-use* it, and more generally you can skip the problem with the new `inline static` feature!)

The rest looks more or less right. I would, however, caution against fixating on `.data` sections and `.bss` sections and compile-time and runtime, because none of that actually matters to C++. What you really have is *static member variables*, and *local variables with static storage duration*. Memorise and use C++ terminology then you can reason about behaviours, rather than about implementation details that don't actually matter unless you're doing weird low-level things that go beyond the scope of C++ itself.

Comment: A definition for `test::x` is needed only if it is odr-used.  Because it is `const` and initialized at the point of declaration, using its value is not odr-use (but forming a pointer or reference would be).

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay, I was speaking broadly, but is that better now?

Comment: Your second paragraph is now better, however that information is tangential to the question.  The remainder of your answer incorrectly affirms the other aspects raised in the question.

Comment: A correct answer to this question MUST address linkage.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not writing an essay on the ins and outs of linkage. OP can get a C++ book to learn more. I'm just answering the question. This answer is correct and I don't know what your problem is. Oh well. Have a good one.